# JUnit - No Spring Boot - Clean H2 Database between each test

Tags: java, junit, h2

I am having issue setting up H2 database for JUnit.
Important to note - I am not using spring boot autoconfiguration.

I want to purge all data between each test.
Test classes extend H2DatabaseConfig class that sets up H2 connection.
And my plan is to purge all data with a @AfterAll annotation.
I dont want to use deleteAll method, like full drop of data (rows and autoincrement reset).

At the moment,
when i run each test individually everything is fine.
But when i run all together i get error

```
jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.database.entity.Team]
```

I know its related to my parent class.
Its related to the way i am recreating session/connection.
But not sure how to fix it.

I appreciate any hint you can give. Thank you in advance

H2DatabaseConfig

```
public class H2DatabaseConfig {
    private static Server server;
    private static Connection connection;
    protected static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private static EntityManager entityManager;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        server = Server.createTcpServer().start();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL", "root", "password");

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("entity-manager-test");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Container.initBeans(entityManager);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

TestClass

```
class FormTeamAddControllerTest extends H2DatabaseConfig {

    private FormTeamAddController formTeamAddController;
    private TeamSavePort teamSavePort;

    @BeforeEach
    public void set() {
        formTeamAddController = new FormTeamAddController();
        teamSavePort = Container.getBean(TeamSavePort.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void shouldSaveTeam() {
        // when
        ValidatorResponse save = formTeamAddController.save("Lowe", "123");

        // then
        assertTrue(save.isOk());
        assertEquals(TeamInputValidator.msgTeamIsCreated("Lowe"), save.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotSaveTeamCauseDuplicateTeamName() {
        teamSavePort.save("Star", BigDecimal.valueOf(123));
        // when
        ValidatorResponse save = formTeamAddController.save("Star", "123");

        // then
        assertTrue(save.hasErrors());
        assertEquals(save.getErrors().get("name"), TeamInputValidator.errTeamNameExists());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotSaveTeamCauseWrongName() {
        // when
        ValidatorResponse save1 = formTeamAddController.save(null, "123");
        ValidatorResponse save2 = formTeamAddController.save("  ", "123");
        ValidatorResponse save3 = formTeamAddController.save("", "123");

        // then
        assertTrue(save1.hasErrors());
        assertTrue(save2.hasErrors());
        assertTrue(save3.hasErrors());

        assertEquals(save1.getErrors().get("name"), TeamInputValidator.errTeamName());
        assertEquals(save2.getErrors().get("name"), TeamInputValidator.errTeamName());
        assertEquals(save3.getErrors().get("name"), TeamInputValidator.errTeamName());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotSaveTeamCauseWrongMembershipFee() {
        // when
        ValidatorResponse save1 = formTeamAddController.save("Star", null);
        ValidatorResponse save2 = formTeamAddController.save("Star", "   ");
        ValidatorResponse save3 = formTeamAddController.save("Star", "");

        // then
        assertTrue(save1.hasErrors());
        assertTrue(save2.hasErrors());
        assertTrue(save3.hasErrors());

        assertEquals(TeamInputValidator.errTeamFee(), save1.getErrors().get("membershipPayment"));
        assertEquals(TeamInputValidator.errTeamFee(), save2.getErrors().get("membershipPayment"));
        assertEquals(TeamInputValidator.errTeamFee(), save3.getErrors().get("membershipPayment"));
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="entity-manager-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.example.database.entity.Team</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user"   value="root" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />

            <!-- Generate the database schema -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>

            <!-- Customize the schema generation behavior -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `@AfterEach` annotation instead of `@AfterAll` to ensure that the cleanup is performed after each individual test, so in `H2DatabaseConfig` class change the `@AfterEach` like below :

```
@AfterEach
public void tearDown() throws SQLException {
    entityManager.clear(); //clear entities from the session
    connection.close();
    server.stop();
}
```

and edit the `persistence.xml` file to include the `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` property with "drop-and-create" to drop and recreate the database schema for each test and ensuring a clean state before running the tests like below:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
```

**update**

about your last comments,better to make sure that you are properly clearing and resetting the persistence context between tests,in your `H2DatabaseConfig` class, add the `entityManager.clear()` method call in the `tearDown()` method and verify that your tests are not sharing or reusing the same instances of entities.each test should create its own instances of entities to avoid conflicts!

Comment: Hello - Thank you :)
` entityManager.clear();` helped. I dont get that exception anymore

However data isnt cleared between tests. I can still see the data from previous test.
Any idea on that?

Comment: So you can try adding the `entityManager.flush();` before the commit!

Comment: I keep trying variations of this but its not working.
Sometimes all tests pass, and sometimes stuff fail with error

jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : 

or 

jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session. Thanks still :)

Comment: @djulb check update section in my answer

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was the solution for the problem.

I had a couple of issues which were blocking. 
For example H2 database has reserved words User, Month, Year

So among other things it was blocking my entity managment system to fully set up and throw weird errors allong the way.